# Liquid Warning: Unexpected character

Tags: syntax-error, jekyll, liquid

To assign class depending on page category I have following in my code:

```
{% assign category_class = 'category-' | append: {{ page.category }} %}
```

As expected I get `<div class="category-sometext"`. But when building I also get warning about an unexpected character in this line.

What's wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `{{ }}` around `page.category` as you are already inside `{% %}`. So:

```
{% assign category_class = 'category-' | append: page.category %}
```